# how to set css of text decoration strikethrough to red color using javascript

Tags: jquery, css

I want to have a red strikethrough, but it still ends up black. This is what I tried:

```
.redRow {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: red;
}
```

Javascript code is:

```
function getCurrentBinRow(elem) {
    $(elem).closest('tr').toggleClass('redRow');
}
```

Comment: Do you want both the text and strike to be red or just one of the two?

Answer (score 3):

Styled Text Decoration Using Javascript,

```
document.getElementById('redRow').style.textDecoration = "line-through";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit your CSS first, setting the color of a td in black and then you can apply your jQuery function:

```js
function getCurrentBinRow(elem) {
  $(elem).closest('tr').toggleClass('redRow');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getCurrentBinRow('td');
});
```

```css
td {
  color: black;
}
.redRow {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>TEST</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/ckr7r0fm/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to give line through and color of line through, to the parent and the content should be in child element.

```
<span style="text-decoration: line-through; color: red;">
 <span style="color: #CCC;">Your content</span>
```

So make your markup accordingly or please give a working fiddle.

I made it inline styles, Please move it to a class and make work with your stuff.

Check this link for [sample](http://jsbin.com/nikeneyaye/1/edit)

Comment: how  to do using javascript

Comment: move the styles to separate class.  give the class to the parent* of the content.

Comment: give a try, if not u cant able to achieve, let me know. I will give a sample for you

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this on a onclick event.

```
<label onclick="addStrikethrough(this)">Test</label>
function addStrikethrough(element){
 element.className = element.className + ' redRow';
}
```

The javascript function needs to be declared in the global namespace.

The css

```
.redRow {
 text-decoration: line-through;
 color: red;
}
```